# facebook login dialog is not loading

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Does anyone know why the Facebook login dialog is not loading on my website..?

As you will see below I have the FB.getLoginStatus inside another function outside window.fbAsyncInit, and calling it from my login button.

No errors appear over the cconsole window..!

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // Additional JS functions here
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '503635172990168', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//http://www.angeloscleanthous.com/chat/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

      };
    function doLogin(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // connected
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
             login();
          } else {
             login();
          }
         });
    }
    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                testAPI();
            } else {
                // cancelled
            }
        });
    }
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
    }
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
    </script>
```

-------------HTML PART------------(Login button)

```
<button onclick="doLogin();" class="classname">Login</button>
```

Comment: Handle the case where response.status is "connected". Maybe you're already connected.

Comment: Smit Patel - That's right, the FB.getLoginStatus() depends of user's status on Facebook. If he's already connected, according to your code ak_47, nothing will happen.

Comment: yes it seems am connected. :S so  tried placing the testAPI() function inside the FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { if (response.status === 'connected') { but nothing is happening

Comment: i have another question. Do you know how can test this on my local machine.. what are the settings i have to change?